# SysSound sample code does not work on iOS 7

Tags: ios

I tested on iPhone 4 with iOS 7, seems like AudioServicesPlaySystemSound and AudioServicesPlayAlertSound both do not work any more.

Answer (score 4):

Both `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` and `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound` work fine for me. Are you sure that

- Your phone is not in silence mode
- Your phone's audio level is not zero
- The sounds you are trying to play are valid (check what `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID` returns as an error)

I put up some code at https://github.com/st3fan/StackOverflow/tree/master/SystemSounds that works for me on iOS 7.0.2 in the Simulator and on an iPhone 5.

Comment: Sorry, I figured out that is my iPhone is broken.

Comment: LOL! In my case, I accidentally switched to Silent mode! :))